# How to create an api that sends mails using node and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

Am trying to create an app that sends mails.
It gets the user input(To, Subject, Message) onClick of the form button sends a mail, and store that mail on mongodb

front end

```
<form>
<span>
to :<input type='text' >
</span>

cc :<input type='text' >
</span>

bcc :<input type='text' >
</span>

<span>
subject :<input type='text' >
</span>

<span>
message :<input type='text' >
</span>
</form>
```

Back end

```
to = 'sender@gmail.com',
cc = 'sender@gmail.com',
bcc = 'sender@gmail.com',
subject = 'A project proposal',
message = 'the body of your mail',
etc...
```

1. Schema

   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

   const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   to: {
       type: String,
     },
     cc: {
       type: String,
     },
     bcc: {
       type: String,
     },
     bcc: {
       type: String,
     },
     subject: {
       type: String,
     },
     message: {
       type: String,
     },
     attachment: {
       type: String,
     },
     date: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
     },

   });

   const Mail = mongoose.model('Mail', UserSchema);

   module.exports = Mail;

A.p.i

```
const Mail = require('../models/Mail');

// Home Page
router.get('/', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('home'));

// Mail
router.get('/mail', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
  res.render('mail', {
    user: req.user,
    mail: req.mail

  })
);

router.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
  const { to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachment, account } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  if (!name || !subject || !message || !account) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      name,
      subject,
      message,
      account
    });
  } else {
    const newMail = new Mail({
      to,
      cc,
      bcc,
      subject,
      message,
      attachment,
      account
    });

    newMail
      .save()
      .then(mail => {
        req.flash(
          'success_msg',
          'mail sent'
        );

      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }
})
module.exports = router;
```

how do i go about it here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Email Templates from MongoDB in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136326/using-email-templates-from-mongodb-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `express-mailer` for sending an email. In this, you can also send an email in CC and Bcc by a comma-separated list or an array. Please check [express-mailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mailer) documentation carefully.

```
var app = require('express')(),
var mailer = require('express-mailer')

mailer.extend(app, {
    emailFrom: "yourEmail@gmail.com", 
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // hostname
    secureConnection: true, // use SSL
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    transportMethod: 'SMTP', // default is SMTP.
    auth: {
        user: 'yourEmail@gmail.com', // Your Email 
        pass: '*******' // Your Password
    }
});

app.mailer.send('../views/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.ejs', { to: 'reciverEmail@gmail.com', subject: 'Your Email Subject'}, function (err, message) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(message);
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use 'nodemailer' module, you can just read their documentation, but i show you a simple example:

```
var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport ({ 
    service: 'gmail', 
    auth: { 
            user: 'youre@gmail.com', 
            pass: 'yourePassword' 
        } 
    });

 module.exports={
     sendAUTH:function(link, email){
        const mailOptions = { 
            from: 'youre@gmail.com',  
            to: email,  
            subject: 'Subject of your email', 
            html: `<a href='`+link+`'>link</a>` 
          };
          transporter.sendMail (mailOptions, function (err, info) { 
            if (err) 
              console.log (err) 
            else 
              console.log (info); 
         });
     }
 }
```